# Sphinx: JSON meta attributes stopped working

Tags: sphinx

I'm currently experimenting with sphinx realtime index. I inserted 4,5 millions documents.

Everything was working OK while my json meta attributes were like this:

```
{"result_type":"publications","publication_type":"essay"}
```

But yesterday, I wanted to add another value in 'publication_type' key and the json
resulted to:

```
{"result_type":"publications","publication_type":["essay","big_text"]}
```

Now I can't find document neither for 'essay', neither for 'big_text'.

The sphinxql query I'm using is like this:

```
select * from url where meta.publication_type='essay';
```

Sphinx version is Server version: 2.1.1-beta (rel21-r3701) running on Debian.

Hope you can help me. Is my json string wrong? Where is my mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SELECT *, ANY(x='essay' FOR x IN meta.publication_type) as p FROM url WHERE p=1;

Supported in 2.2.1-dev since r4217.

Answer (score 0):

This was answered on the sphinx forum:
http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=11486

When store arrays, you access the values by index.

So could do

```
select * from url where meta.publication_type[0]='essay';
```

It doesnt appear to easy to search 'in any position'. So if essay was ever not the first index, it wouldnt work.

Note, I can't claim credit for figuring this out, just passing this information on.

Comment: Humm, strange. I get this error:

sphinxQL> select * from url where meta.publication_type[0]='essay';
ERROR 1064 (42000): sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting BETWEEN (or 8 other tokens) near '[0]='essay''